# Unable to fix crash on Fabric...in recyclerview method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.s.b(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView)' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.java:2534)
       at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:13751)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2964)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2961)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3417)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:6089)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:6061)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:389)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:344)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4011)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:178)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1524)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

This is the crash I am getting on Fabric number of times but unable to solve issue...I found this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38375597...bumped up recyclerview version to 27.1.0 & BuildToolVersion to 27.0.3...still issue persists.

Comment: It is not a common npe...so plz don't downgrade question...its a internal recyclerview npe..need to approach to solve it.

Comment: It will be helpful if you share some details of what you are doing in your code.

Comment: Its simple recyclerview have swipe refresh @VivekSinha

Comment: You need to post relevant code add well